# How can I make sub classes to override a method with a partial implementation?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I would like to obligate all the sub classes of my class to override a method, but I want to give a basic implementation to this method.
I know its sounds a bit weird so here is an explanation:
I have a big code base (C#) which make use of an abstract method. each sub class overrides this method and has its own special needs from this method.
What I did until now was to add an explicit method with a partial implementation in the base class, and I am overriding the abstract method and calling the explicit one in all the sub classes. This way I can avoid duplicate code and still maintain each subclass "special needs".
This solution seems to me pretty messy.
Can someone introduce me to a better solution?

an abstract example:

```
class base{
    method abstract count()
}

class A:base{
    method override count(){
        count()
        print('A')
    }
}

class B:base{
    method override count(){
        count()
        print('B')
    }
}
```

Comment: Java and c# are different languages and have different capabilities. Your code doesn't look like c# so I've removed that tag leaving only the Java tag.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. If you want to "obligate" **all** your child classes to override the method, why do you need a base implementation?

Comment: I mentioned its an abstraction of my code @ZoharPeled

Comment: @Zohar Peled, the example seems to be pseudocode and the method states the actual code is C#.

Comment: @igg I know its a bit tricky, but that's because I want some functionality to happen for all my sub classes with no exception, but also need some special functionality for every child

Comment: So what if it's an abstraction? You're asking for a solution in two different languages - which might probably be a different solution for each language - Pick the language you actually use.

Comment: Fine, I've returned the c# tag and removed the Java one

Comment: @NiaB You mean there's a "base code" that **always** needs to happen, and **sometimes** the children need to provide extra functionality **on top of that**?

Answer (score 0):

Call `base.count()` to invoke the base class's count method.

Edit: I re-read your solution and now I'm not sure if you're already doing this. Maybe decompose the method into several different methods, some of which can be overridden. E.g `count() => countApples() + countOranges() - wormMultiplier() *countWorms();`

Comment: yeah if I got you right this is my current solution- to implement the functionality on another function on base, and then invoke it from sub classes in the overriding methods

Comment: One thing I sometimes do is I have a method MaineOperation() that does some constant stuff then it calls some abstract methods, like CatchCrustaceans() and CookCrustaceans() inside it to do variable stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

Create a public method called `Count` in the BaseClass.
Have that method call the base count implementation method,
and than the abstract count method.
mark the abstract count method protected.

This way, everyone that's inheriting the `Base` class is forced to add it's own implementation, while anyone that's using it must go through the public `Count` class that's also executing the base implementation.

Here's the basic structure of the code:

```cs
abstract class Base
{
    public void Count()
    {
        CountBaseImplementation();
        CountSubClassesImplementation();
    }

    private CountBaseImplementation() 
    {
        // Base implementation here
    }

    protected abstract CountSubClassesImplementation();
}

class A : Base
{
    protected override CountSubClassesImplementation()
    {
        // A specific implementation here
    }
}

class B : Base
{
    protected override CountSubClassesImplementation()
    {
        // B specific implementation here
    }
}
```